# How to match column value between two array with foreach in CI

Tags: codeigniter

how could I get all data from `$uData` where `TraineeID` match with `$aData` using foreach in CI.

print_r($uData);
output

```
Array
(
 [0]=>Array
   (
   [TraineeID]=>FMM003
   [Status]=>P
   [Review]=>1
   [Remarks]=>Allow
   )
 [1]=>Array
   (
   [TraineeID]=>30089
   [Status]=>P
   [Review]=>1
   [Remarks]=>Allow
   )
 [2]=>Array
   (
   [TraineeID]=>30097
   [Status]=>P
   [Review]=>1
   [Remarks]=>countable class not start
   )
)
```

print_r($aData);
output:

```
Array
(
 [0]=>Array
   (
   [TraineeID]=>30089
   )
 [1]=>Array
   (
   [TraineeID]=>30097
   )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Solution Could be Less code and easy to read :-

```
foreach($aData as $value )
{
    $key = array_search($value["TraineeID"], array_column($uData, 'TraineeID'));//get key of matched result
    if($key !== false )//check not falsy
    {
        echo "<pre>"; 
        print_r($uData[$key]);
        echo "</pre>"; 
    }
}
die();
```

Answer (score 2):

just find out below solution..i hope it may help you

```
    $i = 0;
    foreach($uData as $k=>$v)
    {
      if($aData[$i]['TraineeID'] == $v['TraineeID'])
     {
       echo "match";
       $output[] = $v;
     }
     else
     {
      echo "fail";
     }
     $i++;
    }
    print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. It might help you.

```
$result = array();
foreach($uData as $key=> $val) {
    foreach($aData as $key2 => $val2) {
        if($val['TraineeID'] == $val2['TraineeID']) {
            $result[] = $val;
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Comment: here you have used two foreach loops...!!
and i have done it using single loop although it will not take more execution time in your case but when array with big size...sorry man!

Comment: @Kunal, I really appreciate you answer as well. To decide which answer is useful totally depend on user who posted question.

Comment: Yes,it ups to the questioner....but i just shared my opinion my friend!@PHPExpert

Comment: Depending on many parameters (size of data array, server/ram size) recursive foreach loop can freeze the server.

Comment: What about my answer ?